# Title numbers in Table of Contents doesn't align

Tags: latex, r-markdown, bookdown

I have a little problem with the section numbers in the Table of Contents. Until the 9th, all is fine. But the double digits numbers are misaligned, as you can see in the image:

[image: the double digits numbers are misaligned]

In the following example, you can reproduce the error I have. The main problem is with the sections in the TOC with double digits.

````
---
title             : "Title"
subtitle          : "Title"
author: | 
  | Author
  | Working place
  | Email

# keywords          : "keywords"
wordcount         : "X"
documentclass     : article
floatsintext      : no
figurelist        : no
tablelist         : no
footnotelist      : no
linenumbers       : no
mask              : no
draft             : no
tables            : yes
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book: default

header-includes:
   - \usepackage[spanish]{babel}
   - \usepackage{booktabs}
   - \usepackage{placeins}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

\newpage

# Section

\newpage

# Another section

\newpage

# Another section II

\newpage

# Oh! Another section

\newpage

# Yes, one more!

\newpage

# Section v.1

\newpage

# Section IIIVI


\newpage

# Section !!!

\newpage

# Otra sección

\newpage

# This section number doesn't align weel

\newpage

# Oh! Another bad number alignment!
````

I suppose that the problem is with the alignment of the numbers or so, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that reproduces the problem and add the intermediate .tex file to your question?

Comment: I just update the question with a more precise code to reproduce the problem.